# Why am I getting invalid 'width' or 'height' while using shiny application?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm not really sure why this error is coming up when I run this code. Please let me know if you have any ideas. I haven't really successfully been able to height parameter after the } either.

Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


mtcars$cyl = sample(letters[1:5], 32, TRUE)

gg_facet_nrow<- function(p){
  p %>% ggplot2::ggplot_build()  %>%
  magrittr::extract2('layout')       %>%
  magrittr::extract2('panel_layout') %>%
  magrittr::extract2('ROW')          %>%
  unique()                           %>%
  length()
  }

ui <- fluidPage(
 navbarPage(title="title",
         tabPanel("One", 
                  column(3, 
                         wellPanel( selectInput('name', 'NAME', c("A", "B")))),
                  column(9, plotOutput('plot1')))
))


server <- function(input, output) {

 X <- reactive({input$name == "A"})

 p1 <- reactive({
  if(X()){
   p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_grid( . ~ gear )
  }else{
   p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_grid( cyl  ~ gear )
  } 
 return(p1)
 })

he <- reactive(gg_facet_nrow(p1()))

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({p1() }, height = function(){he()*300})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The error I'm getting is

> invalid 'width' or 'height'

Comment: `he()` seems to return 0 in your height function. You can't set the height to 0.

Comment: I'm trying to make the height of renderPlot variable when I'm using `facet_grid` in my shiny application. Do you possibly know what I'm doing wrong in terms of the height function?

Comment: hm... from fiddling around a little bit it seems that the third pipe `%>% magrittr::extract2('panel_layout')` returns `NULL`. Are you sure you're using it correctly?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. By the way, how did you know that `%>% magrittr::extract2('panel_layout')` ?

Comment: I was debugging step by step and looked at what point the pipe operation failed. Nice that you found a solution :)

Comment: In my case it was because a tutorial used `tableOutput` instead of `plotOutput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not using the right height function.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


mtcars$cyl = sample(letters[1:5], 32, TRUE)

library(magrittr)
gg_facet_nrow_ng <- function(p){
  assertive.types::assert_is_any_of(p, 'ggplot')
  p %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot_build() %>%*emphasized text*
    magrittr::extract2('layout') %>% 
    magrittr::extract2('layout') %>%
    magrittr::extract2('ROW') %>%
    unique() %>%
    length()
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title="title",
             tabPanel("One", 
                      column(3, 
                             wellPanel( selectInput('name', 'NAME', c("A", "B")))),
                      column(9, plotOutput('plot1')))
  ))


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  X <- reactive({input$name == "A"})
  
  p1 <- reactive({
    if(X()){
      p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_grid( . ~ gear )
    }else{
      p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_grid( cyl  ~ gear )
    } 
    return(p1)
  })
  
  he <- reactive(gg_facet_nrow_ng(p1()))
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({p1() }, height = function(){he()*300})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```